# Updating ProgressBar from AsyncTask lagging UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have a `Fragment` with a `RecyclerView` and the `RecyclerView`'s `ViewHolder` is holding a `ProgressBar` to show the progress of a downloading process.

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ....
    private ProgressBar progressBar = null;
    ....
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ....
        this.progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progessbar);
        ....
    }
}
```

I created a callback for my `Fragment`:

```
public interface CallbackItemChanged {
    void onItemChanged(final int position);
}
```

And if it is called i do:

```
@Override
public void onItemChanged(final int position) {
    this.adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

And in my `AsyncTask`:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

    this.entry.setProgress(progress[0]);
    this.entry.setProgressString(progress[0] + "%");

    this.callbackItemChanged.onItemChanged(this.entry.getPosition());
}
```

The progress is published successfully but the ui is lagging like hell but i dont know why? The `onProgressUpdate` is running on the ui thread isnt it? I think it should be like that or am i wrong?

How can i get the ui smoothly working while updating the progressbar?

**EDIT**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    this.inputStream = null;
    this.outputStream = null;
    this.connection = null;

    File file = new File(this.entry.getPath(this.context));
    File parent = file.getParentFile();

    try {
        parent.mkdirs();
        file.createNewFile();

        this.connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(this.entry.getUrl()).openConnection();
        this.connection.connect();

        int fileLength = this.connection.getContentLength();

        this.inputStream = this.connection.getInputStream();
        this.outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte data[] = new byte[4096];
        long progress = 0;
        int count;

        while ((count = this.inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
            if (this.isCancelled() || this.entry.isCancelled()) {
                this.handleClose();
                this.handleDelete();

                return null;
            }

            if (fileLength > 0) {
                this.publishProgress((int) ((progress +=count) * 100 / fileLength));
            }

            this.outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.handleDelete();

        return e.toString();
    } finally {
        this.handleClose();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please, show us your whole AsyncTask code. We need to see how you are publishing the progress with the publishProgress method.

Comment: It's not impossible you may be flooding the UI thead with progress updates, but without any code that indicates when and how often you're publishing progress, there's not much we can say about that. When you say the "ui is lagging like hell", do you mean that the UI stutters while scrolling, or perhaps something else, more quantitative?

Comment: i added my `doInBackground` to show where i use `publishProgress`. Yes, the UI is stuttering while scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're publishing the progress inside a loop, so your main thread will be called a lot of times.

You could delay the progress publishing with a simple Thread.sleep():

```
    while ((count = this.inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
        if (this.isCancelled() || this.entry.isCancelled()) {
            this.handleClose();
            this.handleDelete();

            return null;
        }

        // Write the data before publishing the progress
        this.outputStream.write(data, 0, count);

        try{
            // Adjust this value. It shouldn't be too small.
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            // Nothing you can do here
        }finally {
            if (fileLength > 0) {
                this.publishProgress((int) ((progress +=count) * 100 / fileLength));
            }
        }
    }
```

Or you could publish only by increments of x%:

```
while ((count = this.inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
    if (this.isCancelled() || this.entry.isCancelled()) {
        this.handleClose();
        this.handleDelete();

        return null;
    }

    // Write the data before publishing the progress
    this.outputStream.write(data, 0, count);

    if (fileLength > 0) {
        currentProgress = ((progress += count) * 100 / fileLength);
        // Publish only on increments of 1%
        if (currentProgress >= previousProgress + 1) {
            this.publishProgress(currentProgress);
            previousProgress = currentProgress;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: wouldnt this slow down the download process?

Comment: Yes. An alternative is publishing only when you reach a certain difference from the previous progress. I'll edit my answer with an example.